# Waterproofing plumbing stack in bathroom

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, waterproofing

I’m currently designing my new bathroom. I live in a 1970’s apartment block and am on the top floor. My neighbor underneath me has previously had problems with water leaking behind my shower and down the plumbing stack onto her ceiling.

My builder has told me that I won’t need to waterproof the plumbing stack as water won’t get into there any more. He was also unsure he was allowed to waterproof inside the stack. Is this correct?

Should water be able to get down the plumbing stack in the first place?

And are there any issues with waterproofing my floor?

[image]

Comment: If the pipe was installed properly without leaking joint, you shouldn't worry about it. If your bathroom has floor drain, make sure the slope is correct to drain the water, and the drain is not clogged. If no drain, make sure there is no standing water on the floor, after taking bath or shower.

Comment: I really don't understand this question. What does "waterproofing" mean in plumbing? Aren't pipes already waterproof? Are you actually asking about the roof?

Comment: I was talking about the floor underneath the plumbing (behind the wall)

Comment: If the pipes are not leaking then waterproofing the floor is not necessary, If the pipes are leaking then waterproofing the floor is not the correct coarse of action. Than what is the correct course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does waterproof the pluming mean?

Plumbing is designed to keep the water    on the inside of pipes.
If there is a leak in a pipe then the pipe should be repaired.

> He was also unsure he was allowed to waterproof inside the stack. Is
> this correct?

We can  not say what the plumber can or can not do.

Waterproofing the inside of pipes is not  normally done unless it is an underground or otherwise  an inaccessible pipe. In that situation there is a  procedure, [internal pipe coating](https://pipetechusa.com/trenchless-technology/internal-pipe-coating/), to coat the inside of pipe instead of digging it up.

> And are there any issues with waterproofing my floor?

If the pipes are not leaking then waterproofing the floor is not necessary, If the pipes are  leaking then waterproofing the floor is not the correct coarse of action.